# Subsemigroup of permutable semigroup!

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup and $n$ integer greater than 1. A sequence $s_{1}, s_{2},...,s_{n}$ of $n$ elements of $S$ is called permutable if the product $s_{1}s_{2}...s_{n}$, remains invariant, under some nontrivial permutation of its factors, that is, there exists a permutation $\sigma\in S_{n}$ different from the identity, such that $s_{1}s_{2}...s_{n}=s_{\sigma(1)}s_{\sigma(2)}...s_{\sigma(n)}$. A semigroup that satisfies this property we call it a permutable semigroup.
I am quite sure that every sub-semigroup of this semigroup is also permutable, but I am stuck in showing it?? Can someone help please??

Comment: To clarify: you say that a semigroup is permutable if there exist $n \geq 2$, a permutation in $\sigma \in S_n$, and $n$ elements $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ such that $s_1\cdots s_n = s_{\sigma(1)} \cdots s_{\sigma(n)}$? So any monoid is permutable?

Comment: Or do you want this to hold for *any* finite sequence of elements?

Comment: For any finite sequence of elements.

Comment: If you write the definition correctly, that is, with the appropriate quantifiers, then the proof should be obvious.

Comment: Yes this should hold for any finite sequence of elements.

Comment: Can you please clarify more "with the appropriate quantifiers"??

Comment: Lola-- If it is to hold "for any finite sequence of elements" then for distinct $a,b$ of the semigroup the product $ab$ should be permutable. Here $S_2$ has only one nontrivial permutation, so this would imply $ab=ba$ and then the semigroup is commutative. Do you want that?

Comment: If I have this: Assume that $S$ is a permutable semigroup, and $s_{1},s_{2},...,s_{n} \inS$, then there exists a non-trivial permutation $\sigma \inS_{n}$ such that $s_{1}s_{2}...s_{n}=s_{\sigma(1)}s_{\sigma(2)}...s_{\sigma(n)}$. If $S'$ is a sub-semigroup of $S$ and let's say $s'_{1},s'_{2},...,s'_{n} \inS'$( the obviously  $s'_{1},s'_{2},...,s'_{n} \inS$ as $S'\subset S$). Then there exists a non-trivial permutation( can we take the same permutation??) $\sigma\in S_{n}$ such that $s'_{1}s'_{2}...s'_{n}=s'_{\sigma(1)}s'_{\sigma(2)}...s'_{\sigma(n)}$, Can someone confirm if this is correct?!